# Can I add the same marker in different ArrayLists?

Tags: android, list, google-maps, marker

I would like to know how can I add for example the same marker into different array lists. I have let's say 5 array lists and 7 markers. I am adding the markers to the map, adding each marker to it's corresponding list and filter to display or hide the markers according to the list selected by the user. Everything works fine when the lists contain different markers, but when I have common markers in two lists the common marker will be kept only in the last list added.

```
List<Marker> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> secondList= new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> thirdList= new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> fourthList= new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> fifthList= new ArrayList<>();

 Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong1).title("MARKER1").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker1"));
 Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong2).title("MARKER2").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker2"));
 Marker marker3 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong3).title("MARKER3").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker3"));
 Marker marker4 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong4).title("MARKER4").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker4"));
 Marker marker5 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong5).title("MARKER5").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker5"));
 Marker marker6 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong6).title("MARKER6").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker6"));
 Marker marker7 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong7).title("MARKER7").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker7"));

firstList.add(marker1);
secondList.add(marker2);
secondList.add(marker3);
thirdList.add(marker1);
thirdList.add(marker4);
fourthList.add(marker5);
fifthList.add(marker6);
fifthList.add(marker7);
fifthList.add(marker1);
fifthList.add(marker2);
```

So when I filter the markers by lists for example if I filter for firstList no marker will be displayed, if I filter for thirdList only marker4 will be displayed and if I filter for fifthList than al the markers will be displayed including marker1. So the list keeps only the last added common items. So how can I make it so that the lists will keep all their objects even though they are common to other lists?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I don't know if this is exactly what you suggested, but I did this and now the filter is working properly. By doing this I have another problem.

```
List<Marker> firstList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> secondList= new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> thirdList= new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> fourthList= new ArrayList<>();
List<Marker> fifthList= new ArrayList<>();

firstList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong1).title("MARKER1").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker1")));
secondList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong2).title("MARKER2").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker2")));
secondList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong3).title("MARKER3").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker3")));
thirdList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong1).title("MARKER1").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker1")));
thirdList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong4).title("MARKER4").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker4")));
fourthList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong5).title("MARKER5").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker5")));
fifthList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong6).title("MARKER6").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker6")));
fifthList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong7).title("MARKER7").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker7")));
fifthList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong1).title("MARKER1").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker1")));
fifthList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLong2).title("MARKER2").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon)).snippet("Snippet marker2")));
```

Now I want to add OnInfoWindowClickListener to my markers info window. Each marker must open a new activity. Before doing this modification I was adding all the markers to the a private Map allMarkersMap = new HashMap(); and I was adding every marker to the HashMap with allMarkersMap.put(marker1, Marker1.class);

```
 GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener MyOnInfoWindowClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Class cls = allMarkersMap.get(marker);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, cls );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

How can I do this now?

Answer (score 0):

Your markers have the same references, that's what leads you to this behaviour.
Instead of creating and passing markers, you should create `MarkerOptions` and when you add a marker to your array list then create a new `Marker`. `MarkerOptions` is the object which keep the informations you want for your markers, that's the only object which should be instantiated once.

Comment: I have updated my code above. Now the filter is working but I encounter another problem. Please look at the edited question.